# Add a class to any element on the page when the mouse enters it, and remove when it leaves

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a small tool for checking the *`properties/style`* of elements in the browser.

- I've got a small script that's main purpose is to add a class to every element that's currently under the mouse. The problem is that the class stays there forever (the outline in this example is also permanent).
- I need to remove the class from every element that's not under the
  cursor. Basically what I'm trying to achieve is to make it work like
  the *`:hover`* selector in CSS.

Is there any way I could achieve this or am I stuck with looping through the elements and adding the event listeners one by one?

I'm kinda lost.

```js
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  e.preventDefault;
  var target = e.target || e.srcElement, text = target.textContent || target.innerText; 
  target.classList.add('hovered');
  
  // just for the sake of this example
  target.style.outline = "3px dotted #5555ff";
}, false);
```

```html
<body style="display: flex;">
  <div style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background: gold; margin: 10px;"></div>
  <div style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background: gold; margin: 10px;"></div>
  <div style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background: gold; margin: 10px;"></div>
  <div style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background: gold; margin: 10px;"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Why don't you use the `:hover` selector? `document.querySelectorAll("*:hover")`

Comment: it didn't quite solve my problem. Thanks for suggestion anyway! Now I have to go to school...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the events mouseover and mouseout to do the action.

Below you can see i have added a eventlistener same as your's for removing the outline style.

Hope This will do the action

```js
document.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  e.preventDefault;
  var target = e.target || e.srcElement, text = target.textContent || target.innerText; 
  target.classList.add('hovered');
  
  // just for the sake of this example
  target.style.outline = "3px dotted #5555ff";
}, false);
document.addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  e.preventDefault;
  var target = e.target || e.srcElement, text = target.textContent || target.innerText; 
  target.classList.add('hovered');
  
  // just for the sake of this example
  target.style.outline = "";
}, false);
```

```html
<body style="display: flex;">
  <div style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background: gold; margin: 10px;"></div>
  <div style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background: gold; margin: 10px;"></div>
  <div style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background: gold; margin: 10px;"></div>
  <div style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background: gold; margin: 10px;"></div>
</body>
```

This also may help you.Using Jquery

```js
$( ".borderchangediv" ).mouseover(function() {
   this.style.outline = "3px dotted #5555ff";
});
$( ".borderchangediv" ).mouseout(function() {
     this.style.outline = "";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body style="display: flex;">
  <div class="borderchangediv" style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background: gold; margin: 10px;"></div>
  <div class="borderchangediv" style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background: gold; margin: 10px;"></div>
  <div class="borderchangediv"  style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background: gold; margin: 10px;"></div>
  <div class="borderchangediv" style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background: gold; margin: 10px;"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: You can see the code just removed the outline style when mouse leaves the element using mouseover and mouseout

Comment: I saw that, but providing only code is only part of the answer. You need to explain what you've done so OP won't just copy and paste your code. They need to understand what they did wrong. That's the whole point of Stackoverflow.

Comment: Don't worry, I fully understand what he's done. My main problem was that I couldn't figure out anything to achieve this effect without using the `for` loop and adding event listeners directly to every single existing element on the page... That would be preatty inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery `hover` event

```
$(element).hover(()=> { element.addClass('class') }, 
   () => {element.removeClass('class')})
```

Comment: I need this code for a browser extension... The smaller it is, the better for the user.
I must slow down the browser only as little as possible. It's not the case on my PC, but I'm sure many people would find it preatty annoying on older machines. JQuery would add a TONE of unnecessary code.

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  e.preventDefault;
  var target = e.target || e.srcElement, text = target.textContent || target.innerText; 
  target.classList.add('hovered');
  
  // just for the sake of this example
  target.style.outline = "3px dotted #5555ff";
}, false);

document.addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  e.preventDefault;
  var target = e.target || e.srcElement, text = target.textContent || target.innerText; 
  target.classList.remove('hovered');
  
  // just for the sake of this example
  target.style.outline = "none";
}, false);
```

```html
<body style="display: flex;">
  <div style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background: gold; margin: 10px;"></div>
  <div style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background: gold; margin: 10px;"></div>
  <div style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background: gold; margin: 10px;"></div>
  <div style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background: gold; margin: 10px;"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  e.preventDefault;
  var target = e.target || e.srcElement, text = target.textContent || target.innerText; 
  
  document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(elm =>{
      elm.classList.remove('hovered');
      elm.style.outline = "3px solid transparent";
  });
          
  target.classList.add('hovered');
  target.style.outline = "3px dotted #5555ff";
}, false);


document.addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  e.preventDefault;
  var target = e.target || e.srcElement, text = target.textContent || target.innerText; 
  target.classList.remove('hovered');
  
  // just for the sake of this example
  target.style.outline = "";
}, false);
```

```html
<body style="display: flex;">
          <div style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background: gold; margin: 10px;"></div>
          <div style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background: gold; margin: 10px;"></div>
          <div style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background: gold; margin: 10px;"></div>
          <div style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background: gold; margin: 10px;"></div>
        </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `mouseleave` event for that.

See the more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseleave_event

Comment: I asked if there is a way to skip adding event listeners to elements *one by one*.

Comment: @AleksanderCiecierski You can get your target on `mousemove` then add the wanted listeners.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a class and not removing it so what you can do is create another event function that will trigger on onmouseleave and mention this

```
target.classList.remove('hovered');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Get all of the elements on the page (You can trim down to a specific tag name if you need to)
// Array.from just converts the HTML Entity Collection to an array you can iterate over
const elements = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("*"));

// Loop over each element and add a listener for mouse over and mouse out
// Mainly to remove the class after you're not hovering it over anymore
elements.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('mouseover', event => {
    event.target.classList.add('your-class');
console.log(event);
  });

  el.addEventListener('mouseout', event => {
    event.target.classList.remove('your-class');
  });
});
```